# In-app Billing service policy

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, policy

I have question regarding In-app Billing service policy on Android.

My company is offering paid service for users on our web site (search for airlines flights), and now we are developing android application that can be used with same subscription purchased on web. We have doubt about in-app purchase policy, do we need to implement In-app Billing service in the app or we can just redirect user to web site purchase page after he hits sign up button?

Comment: You can do whatever you like. Just make sure your website is mobile friendly

Comment: I don't really know the answer to this (legally speaking) but you can have a look at apps like match.com or linkedin.com which have similar practices (paid subscriptions) and see how they deal with it. If they redirect you to their website, I imagine it should be fine for you to do so as well. I can't see why it wouldn't be bear in mind, I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Guys thanks for suggestions, I will check both apps.